# How to load related entity

Tags: entity-framework

The following code, returns `null` for `product`.

```
var product = Context.Tours
   .Where(t => t.TourId == sale.TourId)
   .Select(t => t.Product)
   .First();
```

How is one supposed to do this?

Comment: How is the relationship between Tours and Products? 1-* ?

Comment: We can't see your model so it's EXTREMELY hard to do anything, if i understand, it would be like :
int id = Context.Product.Where(t => t.TourID == sale.TourId);
Or like octavioccl's answer. But again, you would get better answer if you show your model

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Include`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) extension method:

```
var product = Context.Tours
   .Include(e=>e.Product)
   .Where(t => t.TourId == sale.TourId)
   .Select(t => t.Product)
   .First();
```

If you define your navigation property as `virtual` and you don't disable lazy loading, then the related entity will be automatically loaded from the database the first time that is accessed.

Comment: Why isn't it able to load the product without Include?

Comment: With `Include` method you are telling explicitly you want to load the related entity as part of your query, but as I said earlier, if your nav. property is `virtual` it should be loaded the first time is accessed. Please add your model to your question, maybe there is a better way to do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx) will help you to understand some requirements must meet your entities if you want to enable lazy loading

Comment: Sorry, my code was wrong. Instead of `Tours` on the context, I had `Tours.ToList()` under the covers. You don't need `Include` to make the projection in the select work. My question is really bad!

Comment: Well, improve it.

Comment: @GertArnold Its a non-question. The code in the question works. What would an improved question be? "How do I make this code, which works, work?" :)

Comment: It's still a question. A visitor seeing it for the first time will not read all these comments. Quite frustrating when they try to answer it.

Comment: @GertArnold It should be deleted.

Comment: ... put out of its misery.